# dialog box closes on first time but not on second time

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog box that works fine the first time, i.e. when I click the edit button in it, it closes just fine. But the second time, it just doesn't work when I click the edit button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({});
    });
    $('#editButton').click(function() {
        $('#refreshmydiv').load('/path/to/my/phpfile');
        $('#dialog').dialog("close");
    });
});​
```

and here is html

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;">
    <div>
        Input Field1:<input type="text" id="xyz">
    </div>
    <div>
        InPut Field2: <input type="text" id="abc">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="editButton" value="Edit">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="refreshmydiv">
<table class="table table-striped" id="authentication">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($user as $key=>$value){?>
        <tr class="rowData">
            <td class="username"><?php echo $key; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="password"><?php echo $value; ?>
            </td>
            <td><Button type="submit" class="btn">Edit</button>
            </td>
            <td>Delete
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php  } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

if I take out

```
$('#refreshmydiv').load('/path/to/my/phpfile');
```

then it works...
but I need to have load....

Comment: What does the loaded `phpfile` load into the page?

Comment: it loads a table into the div

Comment: Can you post a sample of what it loads?

Comment: ok I added the table in the div

Comment: <div id="refreshmydiv">
<table class="table table-striped" id="authentication"> ....

Comment: just noticed something..when it loads ..it duplicates everything..so now I have 2 ids with id="editButton"..why is it doing that???

Comment: Is the load call loading more than just the table?

Comment: no its not..but it keeps duplicating the div over and over again

Answer (score 4):

OK found the solution. THe dialog box leaves the content outside the body, so we have to remove it before load.

here is what would do

```
 $('#dialog').remove();
 $('#refreshmydiv').load('/path/to/my/phpfile');
 $('#dialog').dialog("close");
```

Thanks guys